# facebook share does not work on mobile but works on desktop

Tags: facebook, share

```
window.open(
                    'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]='+title+'&p[summary]='+description+' &p[url]='+url+'&p[images][0]='+imageUrl+'','facebook-share-dialog',
                    'width=626,height=436');
        });
```

Hi i used the above codes for sharing stuff on facebook and it works fine on desktop browser. However, it looks weird on mobile browser. Below is the screnshot on mobile browser.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to check on a few things:

- What is the UI setting on your mobile browser? (Mobile mode or Desktop mode) Most of the android phones have mobile view by default.

If it is set to mobile mode, use a mobile specific facebook sharing URL.

Venkat